# How to completely remove Azure-Pipelines from Github

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-app

I've added Azure Pipelines as a github app from my repository.

Somehow, many PR-jobs still wait on my azure pipeline to complete (not all, only those to master).

I've done the following:

- Remove Azure-pipeline.yml from master
- Cancelled my Azure Subscription in Github-Marketplace
- Removed the repository from my azure-organization

Still I'm seeing that my PRs to Master wait for AzureJobs to complete.

The marketplace tells me I have no subscription to Azure.

I cannot find a single reference to Azure on my repository (such as settings -> Integration & Services).

Comment: Not get your latest information, what about this issue in your side? Does it work if you uncheck the branches settings as 4c74356b41's suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to go to `settings > branches` and remove\update branch protection rules to not require Azure Devops builds to complete.

Either uncheck `Require status checks to pass before merging` or delete the Azure Devops builds from the list.

[image]